# Admob ads in defferent process

Tags: android, admob

I added admob to my app, but I've come across a problem. I want to show the ads in the main process and a sub process. I registered it in the AndroidManifast as follows:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

I want it to show in the sub process. I find it doesn't make sense...

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add this line in manifiest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and check if you add these correctly

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
android:multiprocess="true"
```

in your "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" manifest element. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:multiprocess="true"/>
```